# Exporting selected column in marketing column DE without SQL

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, data-export

Is there any way to export a selected column from marketing cloud DE with multiple columns.
This can be done with SQL but I am looking for a way without using it as it is for marketers.
Thank you

Comment: Where do you want to export it to? How should the marketers receive the data?

Comment: Any where is ok .SFTP, email or browser download @LukasLunow

Comment: Normal process would be to have a Query Activity, where you will select the subset of data for export, dump it in a new data extension, and use Data Extension Extract, to dump it in a CSV file. Can you add more details to your question, describing in more details, what you want to achieve? Right now it is very vague, and shows very little effort on your part.

Comment: Since you ask for a non-technical solution: just use the Export button in the Contact Builder UI. You can strip unnecessary columns afterwards. That would be the easy manual approach. Everything else would involve sql.